# Send mouse coordinates over Socket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I've been looking around on the site and searching, but I couldn't find anything that answered my question, if there is one that you think answers my question, then I'm sorry and please do link it =)
Anyways, here goes:

I'm trying to send mouse coordinate over socket from client to a server. Right now I can send for example an integer through DataOutPutStream, and keep updating it, but of course mouse coordinates have 2 sets of data, the x and y.

So my question is, how do I send multiple data, and how does the server know which one is x and which one is y?

As you can see in my client, I'm sending an int with the value of 5, but I need to be able to send x and y, and then be able to differentiate between the 2 from the server-side, and use them.

This is what my client is sending atm:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Created by John on 20/04/2015.
 */
public class Client implements Serializable{


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost",1234);
    int testX = 5;


    DataOutputStream out;

    out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    while(true) {
        out.writeInt(testX);

    }

}

}
```

and this is the server:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {

        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
        Socket s = server.accept();
        DataInputStream in;
        in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());




        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(10);
            System.out.println(in.readInt());
        }
    }
}
```

If someone can explain or re-direct me to somewhere that can help me with this, I'd appreciate it a lot!

Have a nice day =)

Comment: Use System.put.print or send a new line character are the int

Comment: Have you considered sending *two* integers? `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) instead and use it on the client side.
Create a class MouseCoordinate containing the two integer coordinates and send an instance of this class via the ObjectOutputStream.

On server side, you'll need an [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) to receive the objects, as well as the same class you created.

So on your client side, replace

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Socket s = new Socket("localhost",1234);
    int testX = 5;


    ObjectOutputStream out;

    out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

    while(true) {
        out.writeObject(new MouseCoordinates(testX,testY));
      // Unshared prevents OutOfMemoryException
      //out.writeUnsharedObject(new MouseCoordinates(testX,testY));


    }

}
```

and in your Server's main method:

```
ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket s = server.accept();
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

while(true) {
  MouseCoordiate coord = (MouseCoordinate) in.readObject();
  // Or use unshared variant as in client:
  // MouseCoordinate coord = (MouseCoordinate) in.readUnsharedObject();
  System.out.println(coord);
  // do something with coordinate...
}
```

Edit:
Your MouseCoordinate class needs the implement the [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface.

Edit #2: 
If you encouter `OutOfMemoryException`s, you may need to reset the OutputStream every once in a while (as described in [this article](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue088.html)), or use the `writeUnsharedObject()` and its corresponding `readUnsharedObject()` methods of the ObjectStreams.

Comment: The thing I don't understand here is, if this is gonna work on different computers (obv the socket would not be local host) then how will I initialize the MouseCoordinate class in the server? Won't only the client have access to that class?

Comment: You'll need the same version (compiled class) on the servers classpath (i.e. create the class once and use it both on the server and on the client side). The ObjectInputStream recognizes the incoming data automatically.

Comment: So computer 1 has server class and MouseData class,
and computer 2 has client class and MouseData class?
is this correct?

Comment: Correct! As you control both, the server and the client, you can have both of them use the same (as in copy the class file within the correct package to both machines) MouseData class

Comment: Ok so the "package com.company;" should be the same on each computer

Comment: The `sleep()` is literally a waste of time.

Comment: Problem I have now is 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.company.MouseData

Comment: @EbolaInspector Then you didn't copy the code correctly. Try using all of it.

Comment: Thx a lot =), I had accidentally commented something out :P

Comment: Main problem with this method is that it lead to `OutOfMemoryError` because output stream store reference to all object that it serialize to maintain reference transparency.

Comment: proof of my point `        ObjectOutputStream stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            }
        });
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();

        for(int i = 0; i< 1000_000_000; i++){
            stream.writeObject(new byte[10000]);

            if(i%1000==0) {
                System.out.println("i = " + i);
                long memory = runtime.totalMemory();
                System.out.println("memory = " + memory);
            }
        }`

Comment: @talex: You're right, but you can avoid this using the `reset()` method of the ObjectOutputStream every once in a while or use `writeUnshared()` and `readUnshared()`

Comment: @octronos Yes. And don't forget about `InputObjectStream`. Put it in your answer please. As well as explanation of why it there,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use an object?

Here's an example:

```
public class Coordinates implements Serializable {

private int x,y;

// include setter and getters
}
```

And send this to the server instead of an int.

Comment: I tried something like this, but then I couldn't get it to work if I put the server in a different project from the client and mouseData, I could only get it to work if the server had access to the mouseData class, but if this is gonna work on 2 different computers, the server wont have access to the class, only the client.
I had something like this:

ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());

MouseData mouseReceive = (MouseData) in.readObject();

System.out.println(mouseReceive.mouseX);

Comment: @EbolaInspector And yet you've marked an identical answer as correct. Curious.

Answer (score 0):

In such simple case you can just write x coordinate then y. And read them accordingly. TCP guarantee sequence of bytes.